# Win32 Biometric Framework with camera

Tags: winapi, biometrics

I was about to purchase a Windows-Hello compatible camera to use the "WINBIO_TYPE_FACIAL_FEATURES" found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbiomet/winbio-biometric-type-constants?fbclid=IwAR3ZWFPL6mm0W6kAPjwoJk1NN75Ij7dTKLByM6VTdarN0zwh99tLy5UIgaA). I successfully use the Biometric Framework for  WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT.

However, in [WinBioOpenSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbioopensession) it says that only the fingerprint is currently supported.

If this is true, how Windows hello uses the framework to login with an IR camera ? with some internal-only API?

Can anyone that owns such a camera verify that the biometric framework works or not?

Comment: Just for clarification, you need someone with, say, a Surface Book, to verify whether Biometric Framework works with a camera?

Comment: It would help of someone could verify that the API works or not, so obviously yes some compatible hardware would be needed.